# discord.py stuck when updating text channel topic

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to update a Text Channel topic every 5 seconds, I made a simple example to show what problem I'm facing, If you let the bot run for a while, it will eventually get stuck on the `TextChannel.edit()` line, I don't know why it's happening, sometimes it runs perfectly fine and other times not.

Here is a simple example:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()  # All but the two privileged ones
intents.members = True  # Subscribe to the Members intent
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.create_task(update_members_topic('Dev2'))

@bot.event
async def update_members_topic():

    dev2_channel = bot.get_channel(1)

    count = 0
    while True:
        await dev2_channel.edit(topic=str(count))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        count += 1

bot.run('XXXX')
```

Comment: The ratelimit for editing a channel is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel, you're simply hitting it. And sadly no, there's no way to bypass this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Łukasz Kwieciński for answering my question:

**"The ratelimit for editing a channel is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel"**